# Use Output from expression part of list comprehension in conditional

Tags: python, python-assignment-expression

I want to call a method and add the returned value to a list only if the value is not None, in place.

Approach 1

```
list = []
for item in items:
    temp = func(item)
    if temp is not None:
        list.append(temp)
```

Approach 2

```
 [func(item) for item in items if func(item) is not None]
```

The first approach is more verbose than I want but accomplishes my goal. The second approach is in place, but requires two calls to func(item). If possible I would like to reuse the first call in a var that I then use in the comparison.

Not proper python but in the vein of what I am looking for

```
 [(a = func(item)) for item in items if a is not None]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [the assignment expression, aka the walrus operator, `:=`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/), introduced in Python 3.8, supports:

```
[a for item in items if (a := func(item)) is not None]
```

The test precedes the production of a value, so you use the walrus in the condition, not the production expression.

Pre-3.8, you're stuck wrapping a listcomp around a `map` or genexpr:

```
[a for a in map(func, items) if a is not None]  # wrapping map
[a for a in (func(item) for item in items) if a is not None]  # wrapping genexpr
```

Both of the above are equivalent; the former might be *slightly* more performant (especially if `func` is a built-in implemented in C), but it's mostly personal preference (I prefer `map` here largely because it's concise; if the mapping wasn't a preexisting function though, I'd use the genexpr to avoid `map`+`lambda`, which is the worst).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you will need to evaluate the value of `a` after it is calculated by `func(item)`.

You can do this within a generator, then evaluate using a filter (which returns a generator as well), then create a list:

```py
list(filter(None, (func(item) for item in items)))
```

Comment: As long as you're using `filter`, may as well use `map` as well: `list(filter(None, map(func, items)))` Note that this will not work if `func` can return non-`None` falsy values that should be kept; you'd just have to wrap a listcomp around the genexpr/`map`.

Comment: Agreed, there are many edge cases here which must be taken into consideration.